# HTML/CSS Image Overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlap

I'm having an issue with the bottom two images moving around/across each other when the browser window is resized. Could anyone give me a hand with that? 
https://jsfiddle.net/z0g3rp57/

Here is my footer code for that section.

```
<div class="footer">
       <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/nrthrntwns"><img src="facebook.png" width="38" height="38" alt="" border="0" class="facebook"></a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                 <a href="https://www.instagram.com/nrthrntwns/"><img src="instagram.png" width="33" height="33" alt="" border="0" class="instagram"></a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                 </div>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

and my CSS

```
/* Footer */

.footer {
  height: 75px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: irem;
 }

.footer h4 {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size 18px;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 50px;
 margin-top: 5px;
  }
.facebook {
margin-top: 22px;
margin-left: 100px;
 }

.instagram {
margin-top: 25px;
margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick tip, there's no need to define the number of columns for each size if they're the same for each. All you need to define is `xs`, the remaining breakpoints will automatically use the same column sizes.

Answer (score 2):

The fiddle is missing the images so it's hard to tell what is happening, but could it be that you just need to add the `img-responsive` class to them?

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

Bootstrap doesn't make images responsive by default.

Bootstrap reference: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: They're just small social media icons(32px). When I resize my browser they move around though. Like the "instagram" logo moves back and forth across the page when its being resized and the facebook one stays put.

Comment: If they are 1 column,  the column width can be as small as 20px if you resize to about a phone's size. Did you try adding the `img-responsive` class?

Comment: Yeah didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You have put `margin-left:100px` to the facebook icon.

It overlap, because the size of the column is too small for the picture and the margin. Try to remove the margin-left.

```
.facebook {
    margin-top: 22px;
}
```

The images can overlap again if the window is too small. So try to enlarge the colomn. In exemple, replace `col-xs-1` by `col-xs-2` :

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/nrthrntwns"><img src="facebook.png" width="38" height="38" alt="" border="0" class="facebook"></a>
</div>
```